use local user password instead of different user/password when connecting to gnome-remote-desktop
Is it possible to connect to Remote Login/GDM in ubuntu 24.04 with the local user account info instead of different login credentials?
gnome 46
ubuntu 24.04

Do not use the built-in remote login. Install and use xrdp if you want to use the local username and password. You may also use xrdp over an ssh tunnel for key based authentication and login. See the "Original Answer" section of this answer
